# RSA Encryption Private Key without Passphrase?

Tags: java, php, encryption, openssl, rsa

I got some documentation from a client, where there is stated a PRIVATE RSA KEY.

I cannot find a way to encrypt a text with that key, without i need to enter another passphase?

They include "demo example" in Java, for how it's done.

```
publicstaticStringsign(StringstringA, StringprivateKey, Stringinput_charset) 
{
   try {
     PKCS8EncodedKeySpecpriPKCS8 = 
         newPKCS8EncodedKeySpec(Base64.decode(privateKey));
         KeyFactorykeyf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
         PrivateKeypriKey = keyf.generatePrivate(priPKCS8);
         java.security.Signaturesignature =              
         java.security.Signature.getInstance("SHA1WithRSA");
         signature.initSign(priKey);
         signature.update(stringA.getBytes("UTF-8"));
         byte[] signed = signature.sign();

         returnBase64.encode(signed);
     } catch (Exceptione) {
           e.printStackTrace();
     }
      returnnull;
 }
```

When I try in PHP, it tells me that the key is wrong. So my answer is, how I can encrypt a text with the key i've gotten from the documentation? Without password for the "private key"?

```
 function encryptData($raw)
  {
       global $privateKey;
       $privateKey = openssl_pkey_get_private($privateKey);

       if (!$privateKey) {
            throw new RuntimeException('Invalid private key or passphrase');
       }

       // Encrypt digest using the key
          $encrypted = "";

           openssl_private_encrypt($raw, $encrypted, $privateKey, OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING);

          return $encrypted;
     }

      encryptData("Hello world!");
```

My Private Key is;

```
MIICdQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAl8wggJbAgEA
AoGBAIpUpl1YsfN5V2iSLDdih1ymU4W0zC05oUYftsT4CE
FFEgPJdqxTqFoaza01+OLbAzewzRvcTjmyFscahx6X3K4oh
1aJ14jrTXCxqc3E4sfPI/QBxioLVusm+jznnBP5h0iiX1gtdkG
Kj1VmrkkX7brMUDH7y6jqod/TqnHMPVAFAgMBAAECg
YAfnmG4jIGAaYf1OxQoRLk0EECfG0hgPgADC1S3iQo6AR
OxEeeyVBzzG5VPtjqBgBYoMJ1xdNXckjxqnkGsWIH0Zrjal
N7NApDNiq76lINk/xXCRZWLjy7BSa/z6rc8mtYbYf57yxbm
VwznO8f2VlWkjQ8fJ8c5+xxqBlvm9hyoAQJBAMvrncsVSt13
a6IsPk4+2IGO73lgXgtBq3mImIZfK63QniAatrDxTe4i6R4l5
DEPUZ5ETObTqeRajjQ1e/boC4UCQQCtqMF3Kh04DNdF
AXgpf79pA81ymDmzwZIcBpD9LTJcNbSORGUq/aWmWSz
naPtRcF+zSAvKjgLzB3QHsdwO1BqBAkAi2vkzt0X+qOTq6
WkU8sULECV6tsdbeHQY5/I6NZYsdLxtd84S2aop6r1Dk
D86cNnrAEBC3jkoVsdvvuYJAXXXkBMlDJcPjIMWX1EbNV
0V2UtBgQ/GGm5nw6zVSHyw0+F4hjw87A5OQknRgPLOD
w7OXa6NHcep2kdipsdVzbwgqX4rilqqFTeJhy/tDiFJKhi4xOm
DQRIdVhhhgZs81
```

Comment: _My Private Key is;_ .... ___Not very private any more___

Comment: Just dummy text

Comment: Phew thats a relief :)

Comment: "How I can encrypt a text with the key i've gotten from the documentation without the password for the private key?" You can't. That's the whole point of the passphrase. It would also be incredibly silly to publish the signing key in the docs. You should be able to submit your own public key somewhere.

Comment: Did you try if the the Java example is working? You can export a private key without password. This is f.e. used on servers for SSL encryption. Otherwise you would need to enter a passphrase on every server restart, which is not very feasible. This is however not recommended for other signing usecases.